# CakePHP Inflector on certain words returns swapped letters

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.4, inflector

I own a content-management system which uses Cake's inflector to output entries with pluralization if I detect there's more than one available.

```
if ($amt >= 2)
$object_name = Inflector::pluralize($object_name);
```

This works well for any object so long as it isn't in the Inflector's "irregular" list.

http://inflector.cakephp.org/The%20Purple%20Cow returns "The Purple Tows"
http://inflector.cakephp.org/Purple%20Cow returns "Purple Pows"
http://inflector.cakephp.org/The%20Purple%20Goose returns "The Purple Teese"
http://inflector.cakephp.org/Purple%20How returns "Purple Hows" as expected

For some reason it's substituting the **last** word's **first** letter with the **first** word's **first** letter, *then* adding an S as expected.

**UPDATE:** CakePHP bug, [documented here.](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6538) Will be fixed in 2.6.5. Question has been modified to avoid confusion.

Comment: Looks like the ticket you opened got closed right away because they thought it was too much of an edge case based on the use of "Purple", which had nothing to do with the bug.

Comment: I think he breezed over my question, so I gave him a more eye-catching example. What's funny here is that I can't figure out why cow even needs to be in the list, like "sex" is. "Sex" turns to "Sexes" which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug specific to the word Cow in the last position. "The Purple Hen" and "Purple Hen" work fine. "Cow Fence" works fine. But "Big Cow" or "The Big Cow" reproduce the bug.

I would recommend looking into opening a ticket using their guidelines [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/tickets.html).

You'll need to [search existing tickets](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=inflector&type=Issues) related to the inflector to see if it has already been reported. There are several other inflector issues, but I didn't find anything when searching for the term cow.

Comment: This is pretty interesting! I did, in fact, test with more than cow: "The Purple Goose", and it still did it! So I looked for Cow through cakephp's lib and it turns out both cow and goose are special entries under "irregular". I guess I had farm life on my mind after studying how chickens produce eggs. They don't need the rooster's sperm to make edible eggs.

Comment: Strange that cow is in the irregular list, where it simply shows `'cow' => 'cows'` in their code.